# Cross-domain Ajax - Why isXmlHttpRequest return false?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, cross-domain

I'm doing an Ajax request like this :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Routing.generate('check_login_ajax'),
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            _username: $('#_username').val(),
            _password: $('#_password').val(),
            _remember_me: false,
            _csrf_token: $('#_csrf_token').val()
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

The php controller :

```
    public function CheckLoginAjaxAction() {
            $request = $this->get('request');

            $success = false;
            $responseCode = 300;
            if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                    $responseCode = 200;
                    $success = true;
            }

            $return = json_encode(array('responseCode' => $responseCode, 'success' => $success));
    }
```

I have, on my xbo.dev site :

```
Object {responseCode: 200, success: true}
```

And I have, on my subdomain blog.xbo.dev :

```
Object {responseCode: 300, success: false}
```

So, my request works but it's not considered as a valid `POST` xml request.
Why ?

By the way, I have another little problem. When I make an Ajax request from the subdomain, it doesn't appear in the Symfony2 debug toolbar. Do you know how to change it and if it is possible ?

[image: Symfony2 debug toolbar]

Thanks

Comment: Cross domain ajax request are forbidden by default by the protocol. If you want to do that you've to explicitely allow it on your server conf

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using jQuery for your AJAX call, in which case jQuery tries to be smart when it detects a cross-domain request and will change the format of the request to JSONP. JSONP effectively just creates a script tag to the requested URL and runs the resultant script (more details on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)). So the request coming into your controller will actually be a GET rather than a POST (because jQuery is requesting a script) and is also why it won't appear in the Symfony toolbar as an AJAX request.

To get around this you should look into [Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://enable-cors.org/) which is specifically to solve doing cross domain AJAX requests like this. The details of implementing this are beyond the scope of this answer and will be contingent on your browser support and JavaScript setup.

Comment: how can we know that jQuery switched to JSONP for this request? Can user validate this somehow? Else it is mere speculation as is. Suggest to augment the answer with a way the user can verify this

Comment: Take a look at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for AJAX, specifically the `dataType` parameter which specifically states: "Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless the request includes jsonp: false in its request options."

Comment: yes, this should be added in the answer, yet we do not know which version of jquery is used in the site, so a way to verify this would be helpful if possible

Comment: @JohnNoel : Indeed I'm using jQuery for my AJAX call. Okay thank you, I now understand why it doesn't appear on the toolbar. I looked million links about CORS, but I didn't succeed to make it work...
I'm under jQuery 2.1.3.